# Вопросы проектирования современного шаблонного синглтона

Tags: c++, c++11

Хочу реализовать несколько классов менеджеров и логгер с возможностью создания в единственном экземпляре посредством наследования от синглтона. Сейчас остановился на такой реализации:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    static
    std::shared_ptr<T> get_instance(Args... args)
    {
        if (!instance_)
        {
            instance_ = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        return instance_;
    }

    static
    void destroy_instance()
    {
        instance_.reset();
    }

private:
    static std::shared_ptr<T> instance_;
};

template <class T> std::shared_ptr<T> Singleton<T>::instance_ = nullptr;
```

Вопросы следующие:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что паттерн «синглтон с контролем времени жизни объекта» подразумевает наличие метода типа `destroy`? Начинал я с классического синглтона Мейерса со статической локальной переменной в функции `instance`, но удалить таковую было нельзя (деструктурирование после выхода из `main` было неудобно по ряду причин - одна из них - было несколько подобных объектов, зависящих друг от друга, порядок удаления неопределен). Поэтому решил реализовать что-то с удалением.
2. Является ли происходящее в `GetInstance` потокобезопасным? Не очень знаком с моделью памяти еще, надо ли использовать `std::call_once`?
3. Какие проблемы есть в такой реализации и как ее можно улучшить? Помимо использования, например, `std::unique_ptr`. Может, есть вообще другая реализация, принятая в современном мире?

Comment: Для начала стоит определиться с набором фич, которые вы хотите получить. В данном виде реализация выглядит весьма посредственно. Во-первых есть чисто языковые огрехи: не стоит возвращать сырой указатель, не получится передать в конструктор целевого класса аргументы, в конструкторе самого Singleton что-то непонятное происходит. Во-вторых следует четко разграничивать ответственность, а не пытаться спихнуть все в один котел. Вот кто в этом коде владеет экземпляром целевого объекта, кто отвечает за многопоточность? Тут можно хорошо попрактиковаться в policy-based design.

Comment: @VTT сырой указатель меняю на smart pointer, не вопрос. По поводу передачи аргументов - применим perfect forwarding, конструктор уберу.

Comment: @VTT немного не понял Ваш комментарий про владение объектом. Он же как статический указатель в самом классе, а пользуемся мы наследованием от этого синглтона.

Comment: Ну вот кто в вашем коде отвечает за вызов `destroy_instance`? Явно какой-то внешний код. Который без дополнительных усилий не будет выполнен автоматически. Если в классе будет статический `unique_ptr` то это будет подправлено. Но при этом если внешний код не позаботится, то существование синглетона будет продленно на неопределенный срок. т.е. по-умолчанию с таким подходом пользователь не контролирует время жизни объекта, он только опционально может его разрушить пораньше.

Comment: @VTT так (наверное, shared_ptr лучше) ? Или Вы предлагали убрать destroy_instance? В том то и проблема, что я не понимаю, как организовать этот destroy_instance. Если я его вызову, то как гарантировать, что никому не потребуется снова экземпляр этого синглтона? И потом, если потребуется, то лучше вообще пока не разрушать, конструирование может быть дорого.

Comment: Так суть в том, что можно реализовать множество различных подходов, в зависимости от того, что вы хотите получить. Например вместо вопроса "как гарантировать, что никому не потребуется снова экземпляр этого синглтона" стоило бы задать вопрос "нужно ли это гарантировать"? Альтернативные подходы вместо ленивой инициализации могут реализовать `if(!instance_){ abort(); }` или `assert(instance_);` или создание с `call_once` вызывающее `abort` во время второй попытки. С методом `destroy` тоже можно реализовать массу различных подходов.

Comment: Хорошо, поэкспереминтирую, спасибо.

Comment: При чем среди этих различных подходов разные могут быть полезны в разных сценариях использования, нет никакой серебряной пули.

Comment: Еще про многопоточность: часто разговор сводится к безопасности инициализации или доступа из разных потоков (хотя это не всегда нужно). А ведь еще есть варианты с thread-local синглетонами. Как минимум один из них (собственно TSL) всегда присутствует в программе.

Comment: @VTT, возможно, в этом случае вообще стоит использовать фабричный метод, возвращающий `shared_ptr` на объект синглтона, создаваемый на куче в момент первого вызова этого метода.

Comment: @VTT (и да, я видел ответ ixSci, но вы же хотите контролировать время жизни синглтона, максимально его укоротив)

Answer (score 2):

Первое, если нужно контролировать время жизни, то естественно нужен метод, который можно вызвать для создания и метод для удаления объекта. Назвать оные можно как угодно, но они должны быть доступны.

Второе, потокобезопасным, происходящее в `GetInstance`, естественно, не является. Хотите потокобезопасную инициализацию используйте мьютексы с [двойной блокировкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) (в C++11 в этом нет смысла), либо же просто используйте `std::call_once` (это нормальное C++11-решение). Но тут встаёт вопрос, если у нас есть потокобезопасное создание, то как быть с удалением? Его тоже нужно делать потокобезопасным? А как это сделать? Что делать если один поток удалил, а второй пытается использовать? На эти вопросы Вам нужно ответить самостоятельно.

Третье, помимо упомянутого выше, есть пара замечаний. Возвращать `shared_ptr` не имеет смысла: возвращайте «сырой» указатель (а ещё лучше — ссылку). Зачем Вам нужна механика `shared_ptr` в интерфейсе? Дальше, если уж создаёте `shared_ptr`, то используйте `make_shared`: это стандарт де-факто, да и эффективнее оно. Ну и применив предыдущий совет, получается, что `shared_ptr` вообще не нужен — достаточно `unique_ptr`.

P.S. используя Вашу реализацию, наследование вообще не нужно. Достаточно использовать так:

```
using Logger_t = Singleton<Logger>;
//...
Logger_t::get_instance()->logMe("me the logger!");
```

Comment: А разве двойная блокировка безопасна? Мне казалось, что для неё требуется довольно сильная модель памяти.

Comment: @VladD, правильно реализованная — безопасна, правда реализовать её правильно не очень легко. Я просто её упомянул, имея `std::call_once` нет смысла её использовать.

Comment: Я имел в виду это: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-and-the-perils-of-double-checked-locki/184405726

Comment: @VladD, да, я читал эту статью. Там всё написано правильно, просто там нет примера, который решает все их проблемы, потому что они апеллируют исключительно к языку C++, который не имел на тот момент средств, для обеспечения корректности алгоритма. Чтобы исправить код, достаточно добавить 2 барьера: либо C++11, либо платформозависимых и всё станет корректным.

Comment: А можно всё-таки ссылку? Если барьеры внутри, то они не сильнее внутреннего мьютекса (который по сути полный барьер). А если снаружи, то это как бы уже не DCL?

Comment: @VladD, ну, [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6009244/643393), к примеру. _«А если снаружи, то это как бы уже не DCL?»_ барьер не считается блокировкой.

Comment: А, ну окей, мы усилили переменную `pInstance`. Теперь её _любое_ чтение с барьерами. Тогда это не сильно лучше просто мьютекса (хотя и лучше)?

Comment: @VladD, по ссылке приведено грубое решение, мы можем сделать лучше. Использовать минимальные барьеры (acquire/release), которые на некоторых архитектурах будут пустыми инструкциями. Так что нет, это сильно лучше простого мьютекса, который вполне может сразу в системный вызов преобразоваться. Всё wait- и lock-free программирование построено на барьерах, кстати.

Comment: Ну, хм, на тех же архитектурах (с сильной моделью памяти) внутрипроцессный мьютекс вполне может быть довольно эффективным. То есть на самом деле там не мьютекс эффективный, а доступ к памяти неэффективный. Я бы всё же назвал это double-checked one-and-half-locking, как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

У таких глобальных сущностей есть ряд глобальных проблем - они нарушают ряд идей *экономного проектирования*, как то:

- явное лучше неявного
- поменьше сцепления

По первому пункту - явное указание зависимости между частями программы позволяет легко превратить ее в *подводную лодку* - хорошо структурированное изделие, легко разделяемое на отдельные, самостоятельные отсеки. В моей практике есть случай, причем прямо связанный с логированием - предполагалось, что в продукте все параллельные дела будут делаться только в мультипроцессе, и никогда - в мультитреде, поэтому класс логирования был всегда однопоточным. И тут, 20 лет спустя, вдруг оказалось, что одна операция ну вот прекрасно делается в мультитреде - а все завязано на то самое логирование. В итоге закрытие нехитрой фичи заняло уйму времени на форк отдельного, более умного логирования, способного на мультитред. Теперь в одной части проекта одно логирование, а в другой - другое.

Вывод

- любая, подложенная под основу проекта глобальная сущность, да еще с автоматическим времени жизни, на каком-то этапе развития проекта вылезет вам боком, причем очень сильно.
- на этапе раннего проектирования невозможно предусмотреть все повороты судьбы проекта и окружающих его технологий в будущем.

Итого, чтобы у вас все было хорошо и красиво - **реализуйте зависимости явно**.

Одно только наличие в C++ таких глобальных чудес как, `cin`, `cout`, `new`, `delete` создают столько чудес при мультимодульной мультикомпиляторной сборке, что лучше бы этих глобальностей не было ВОВСЕ.

Comment: А как Вы предлагаете реализовывать тот же логировщик? Экземпляр лог-класса нужен много кому, а где его размещать? Система типа мультитред.

Comment: Создавать на куче, в мейне. А потом всем-всем-всем раздавать явно указатель на него.

Comment: Хорошо. А что насчет концепции единственного экземпляра тогда? В некоторых случаях создание другого экземпляра просто ненужно, а в некоторых и опасно (если подразумевается что-то типа менеждера памяти).

Comment: Понимаете, в какой-то момент может возникнуть важная для бизнеса задача - аккуратно выпилить часть функционала в отдельный продукт. В случае с явными зависимостями - вы аккуратно переносите все в отдельный проект и добиваетесь компилируемости. В противном случае - вы можете что-то забыть.

Что касается менеджера памяти - вдруг может оказаться, что менеджеров памяти нужно два. И что делать?

Comment: То есть например - у вас есть один большой и универсальный менеджер памяти, но в какой-то момент вам понадобится другой менеджер памяти, для отдельной подзадачи.

Тогда вы должны в вашем глобальном менеджере сделать детектор того, что его начала вызывать эта отдельная задача, и переподстроить его под нее. 

В случае с отдельным менеджером - вы просто реализуете дополнительную ветку менеджера памяти и в отдельную задачу передеаете именно его, а она будет передавать его во все задачи от которых зависит - и все работает четко и гибко!

Comment: Начали за здравие, а кончили за упокой... Дело в том, что синглетон, как и другие паттерны, может присутствовать безотносительно наличия некого участка кода с соответствующем именем. Тот же пример: если есть некоторый универсальный менеджер памяти, то он будет синглетоном, даже если его передавать как аргумент функции во все места использования. Просто в этом случае будет оверхед по сравнению с написанием специализированного метода для его получения в любом месте.

Comment: @VTT - в таком случае, синглтоном должен быть не сам менеджер, а класс - фабрика по производству таких менеджеров. И давайте без эмоциональных выпадов, мы обсуждаем технический вопрос.

Comment: Попытка побыстрей начать писать про "эмоциональных выпадов" вместо хоть какой-то объективной аргументации выглядит крайне беспомощно. Откуда вдруг появилась фабрика по производству менеджеров? Ее наличие или отсутствие никак не будет влиять не существование синглетона-менеджера.

Comment: @VTT в вашем сообщении я ничего информативного для себя не увидел. Я утверждаю, что любая часть программы должна легко изыматься из нее и понижаться в ранге с синглтона на обычный класс. Ваши возражения?

Comment: Откровенно говоря, я не очень понял суть этого утверждения. (в нем подразумевается, что любая часть программы является синглетоном?) Любой *экземпляр* любого класса может (потенциально) быть синглетоном, а может и не быть. Наличие синглетонов (даже в явной форме, т.е. с кодом для получения экземпляра) само по себе не препятствует разделению программы (для тестирования например). А вот возникновение сильного сцепления очень может. Но оно не является прямым следствием существования синглетонов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74017/discussion-between-gbg-and-vtt).